# How to delete records from multiple tables in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying like :-
In sequelize

```
sequelize.query("Delete from table1 where id=1;Delete from table2 where id=124;",{
    replacements: {},
    type: sequelizeObj.QueryTypes.DELETE
  })
```

It throws error like:-

ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

But the same syntax is working for selecting the records.

Comment: You're using a delete command to select records? And it works?

Comment: @Jaybird for select there is QueryTypes.SELECT instead of QueryTypes.DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multiple queries you need to pass `multipleStatements: true` :

Like this :

```
sequelize.query("Delete from table1 where id=1;Delete from table2 where id=124;",{
    replacements: {},
    type: sequelizeObj.QueryTypes.DELETE ,

    dialectOptions: {
        multipleStatements: true // <---- HERE
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried the same adding dialectOptions. now getting error:--

ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM user_educations WHERE user_id=3840;DELETE from user_families WHERE u' at line 1